# Increment/decrement button React.js/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, increment, decrement

I know similar questions have been asked, but I couldn't find one which I could adapt to my code (possibly cause I am still new to Redux).
So, I am editing the cart functionality which was already written and where I already have two functions:

1. Update the quantity number whenever user adds or removes product(s).
2. Update the total price of added products.
   At the moment, quantity number is displayed via input with its default arrows (therefore it's not very touchscreen-friendly), and the user can't really delete the starting number 1 in order to 'manually' change the quantity by typing in.
   My job is to make increment and decrement buttons along with different input where user will also be able to type in the desired quantity. How can I do this?

```
export function calculateTotal(cart) {
    let totalUSD = 0;
    Object.keys(cart).forEach((itemName) => {
      totalUSD += cart[itemName].price * cart[itemName].quantity;
    });
    return totalUSD.toFixed(2);
  }
  export function calculateTotal(cart) {
    let totalUSD = 0;
    Object.keys(cart).forEach((itemName) => {
      totalUSD += cart[itemName].price * cart[itemName].quantity;
    });
    return totalUSD.toFixed(2);
  }
  export function calculateTotalQuantity(cart) {
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    Object.keys(cart).forEach((itemName) => {
      totalQuantity += cart[itemName].quantity;
    });
    return totalQuantity;
  }
```

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Cart.css";
import Navbar from './Navbar.jsx';
import Footer from './Footer.jsx';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { changeItemQuantity } from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';
import { calculateTotal } from '../features/utilities/utilities.js';
import { removeAll } from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';

export default function Cart() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart); // * Note
  const onInputChangeHandler = (name, input) => {
    // If the user enters a bad value...
    if (input === '') {
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, convert the input into a number and pass it along as the newQuantity.
   const newQuantity = Number(input);

    dispatch(changeItemQuantity(name, newQuantity));

  };

  const onRemoveAll = () => {

    dispatch(removeAll());
  };
  // Use the cart and currencyFilter slices to render their data.
  const cartElements = Object.entries(cart).map(createCartItem);
  const total = calculateTotal(cart);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar/>
      <div id="cart-container">
        <ul id="cart-items">
          {cartElements == '' ? <div className="cart-empty">Your cart is empty</div> : cartElements}
        </ul>
        <div className="price-btn-container">
          {cartElements.length > 0 ? <button
              onClick={() => onRemoveAll()}
              className="remove-all"
            >
              Remove All
            </button> : <div></div>}
          <h3 className="total">
            Total{' '}
            <span className="total-value">
              ${total} 
            </span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  );

  function createCartItem([name, item]) {
    if (item.quantity === 0) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <li className="cart-list" key={name}>
        <img src={item.img}/>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{item.type}</p>
        <div className="quantity-container">
          <p>Quantity:</p>
          <input 
          type="number" 
          className="item-quantity" 
          name="quantity" 
          value={item.quantity}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onInputChangeHandler(name, e.target.value);
          }}/>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
};
```

```
export const addItem = (itemToAdd) => {
    return {
      type: 'cart/addItem',
      payload: itemToAdd,
    };
  };

  export const removeAll = () => {
    return {
      type: 'cart/removeAll',
      payload: initialCart
    }

  }
  
  export const changeItemQuantity = (name, newQuantity ) => {
   return {
      type: 'cart/changeItemQuantity',
      payload: {
        name,
        newQuantity
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  const initialCart = [];
  export const cartReducer = (cart = initialCart, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'cart/addItem': {
        const { name, price, img, type } = action.payload;
        
        // if the item already exists, increase the quantity by 1, otherwise set it to 1
        const quantity = cart[name] ? cart[name].quantity + 1 : 1;
        const newItem = { price, img, type, quantity };
  
        // Add the new item to the cart (or replace it if it existed already)
        return { 
          ...cart, 
          [name]: newItem 
        };
      }
      case 'cart/removeItem':
        return cart.filter(item => item !== action.payload);
        
      case 'cart/removeAll':
        return initialCart;

      case 'cart/changeItemQuantity': {
        const { name, newQuantity } = action.payload;
        const itemToUpdate = cart[name];
        const updatedItem = {
          ...itemToUpdate,
          quantity: newQuantity
        }
        // Create a copy of itemToUpdate and update the quantity prop.
        return {
          ...cart,
          [name]: updatedItem 
        }
      }
      default: {
        return cart;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please transfer and make it work in a code sandbox. That helps to see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two new actions/reducer cases to increment/decrement the item quantity.

```js
export const addItem = (itemToAdd) => ({
  type: 'cart/addItem',
  payload: itemToAdd,
});

export const removeAll = () => ({
  type: 'cart/removeAll',
  payload: initialCart
});
  
export const changeItemQuantity = (name, newQuantity) => ({
  type: 'cart/changeItemQuantity',
  payload: { name, newQuantity }
});

export const const incrementItemQuantity = (name) => ({
  type: 'cart/incrementItemQuantity',
  payload: name
});

export const const decrementItemQuantity = (name) => ({
  type: 'cart/decrementItemQuantity',
  payload: name
});
  
const initialCart = {};

export const cartReducer = (cart = initialCart, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'cart/addItem': {
      const { name, price, img, type } = action.payload;
        
      // if the item already exists, increase the quantity by 1, otherwise set it to 1
      const quantity = cart[name] ? cart[name].quantity + 1 : 1;
      const newItem = { price, img, type, quantity };
  
      // Add the new item to the cart (or replace it if it existed already)
      return { 
        ...cart, 
        [name]: newItem 
      };
    }

    case 'cart/removeItem':
      return cart.filter(item => item !== action.payload);
        
    case 'cart/removeAll':
      return initialCart;

    case 'cart/changeItemQuantity': {
      const { name, newQuantity } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...cart,
        [name]: {
          ...cart[name],
          quantity: newQuantity
        } 
      }
    }

    case 'cart/incrementItemQuantity':
      const name = action.payload;
      return {
        ...cart,
        [name]: {
          ...cart[name],
          quantity: cart[name].quantity + 1
        } 
      }

    case 'cart/decrementItemQuantity':
      const name = action.payload;
      return {
        ...cart,
        [name]: {
          ...cart[name],
          quantity: Math.max(1, cart[name].quantity - 1)
        } 
      }

    default:
      return cart;
  }
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Cart.css";
import Navbar from './Navbar.jsx';
import Footer from './Footer.jsx';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  changeItemQuantity,
  decrementItemQuantity,
  incrementItemQuantity,
  removeAll
} from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';
import { calculateTotal } from '../features/utilities/utilities.js';

export default function Cart() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart); // * Note

  const onInputChangeHandler = (name, input) => {
    // If the user enters a bad value...
    if (input === '') {
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, convert the input into a number and pass it along as the newQuantity.
    const newQuantity = Number(input);

    dispatch(changeItemQuantity(name, newQuantity));
  };

  const onRemoveAll = () => dispatch(removeAll());
  const incrementItem = (name) => dispatch(incrementItemQuantity(name));
  const decrementItem = (name) => dispatch(decrementItemQuantity(name));

  function createCartItem([name, item]) {
    return (
      <li className="cart-list" key={name}>
        <img src={item.img}/>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{item.type}</p>
        <div className="quantity-container">
          <p>Quantity:</p>
          <input 
            type="number" 
            className="item-quantity" 
            name="quantity" 
            value={item.quantity}
            onChange={(e) => {
              onInputChangeHandler(name, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={decrementItem.bind(null, name)}>
            -
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={incrementItem.bind(null, name)}>
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
  
  // Use the cart and currencyFilter slices to render their data.
  const cartElements = Object.entries(cart)
    .filter(([,item]) => item.quantity)
    .map(createCartItem);

  const total = calculateTotal(cart);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div id="cart-container">
        {cartElements.length
          ? (
            <ul id="cart-items">
              {cartElements}
            </ul>
          ) : <div className="cart-empty">Your cart is empty</div>
        }
        <div className="price-btn-container">
          {!!cartElements.length && ( // <-- coerce length to boolean
            <button
              onClick={onRemoveAll}
              className="remove-all"
            >
              Remove All
            </button>
          )}
          <h3 className="total">
            Total{' '}
            <span className="total-value">
              ${total} 
            </span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

If you don't want the extra actions/reducers, you could handle it with the `changeItemQuantity` action.

```js
case 'cart/changeItemQuantity': {
  const { name, newQuantity } = action.payload;

  return {
    ...cart,
    [name]: {
      ...cart[name],
      quantity: Math.max(1, newQuantity),
    } 
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Cart.css";
import Navbar from './Navbar.jsx';
import Footer from './Footer.jsx';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  changeItemQuantity,
  removeAll
} from '../features/cart/cartSlice.js';
import { calculateTotal } from '../features/utilities/utilities.js';

export default function Cart() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart); // * Note

  const onInputChangeHandler = (name, input) => {
    // If the user enters a bad value...
    if (input === '') {
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, convert the input into a number and pass it along as the newQuantity.
    const newQuantity = Number(input);

    dispatch(changeItemQuantity(name, newQuantity));
  };

  const onRemoveAll = () => dispatch(removeAll());
  const incrementItem = (name, item) => dispatch(
    changeItemQuantity(name, item.quantity + 1)
  );
  const decrementItem = (name, item) => dispatch(
    changeItemQuantity(name, item.quantity - 1)
  );

  function createCartItem([name, item]) {
    return (
      <li className="cart-list" key={name}>
        <img src={item.img}/>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{item.type}</p>
        <div className="quantity-container">
          <p>Quantity:</p>
          <input 
            type="number" 
            className="item-quantity" 
            name="quantity" 
            value={item.quantity}
            onChange={(e) => {
              onInputChangeHandler(name, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={decrementItem.bind(null, name, item)}>
            -
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={incrementItem.bind(null, name, item)}>
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
  
  // Use the cart and currencyFilter slices to render their data.
  const cartElements = Object.entries(cart)
    .filter(([,item]) => item.quantity)
    .map(createCartItem);

  const total = calculateTotal(cart);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div id="cart-container">
        {cartElements.length
          ? (
            <ul id="cart-items">
              {cartElements}
            </ul>
          ) : <div className="cart-empty">Your cart is empty</div>
        }
        <div className="price-btn-container">
          {!!cartElements.length && (
            <button
              onClick={onRemoveAll}
              className="remove-all"
            >
              Remove All
            </button>
          )}
          <h3 className="total">
            Total{' '}
            <span className="total-value">
              ${total} 
            </span>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I did try the first method. Didn't work then and doesn't work now. The second one (using changeItemQuantity) does provide the working buttons, but it comes with few side effects, one of them being another 0 displayed when there aren't any products, but I think I can manage my way around this. Thanks for helping, yet again.

Comment: @Igor Oh, sorry, the first example probably didn't work because I forgot to access the `name` from the `action.payload`. I've updated answer. The 0 displaying might have been an un-coerced boolean, which I'll also check in the code I've suggested.

Comment: It's okay, I like the second one better anyway. :) So, I managed to stop zero from showing by bringing back my original ternary operator in the price-btn-container, and I even fixed a lot of earlier issues by playing around with your example (big thanks). The only thing I can't figure out is how to enable user to clear the input (it simply won't let me delete the first number). I think it has something to do with my onChange event. Would you agree?

Comment: @Igor It's the `if (input === "")` check in the handler. If the user clears the input, the handler ignores the change and doesn't update the state that is setting the input's value, so in the UI it looks as if nothing happened, e.g. that they can't clear it. If you would like users to be able to clear the input and enter numbers manually then you'll need to remove this check.