# React Redux changing state has some problems

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
const [updateCartItems, setUpdateCartItems] = useState([])

const { cartItems, loading: cartLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer)
console.log(cartItems)

useEffect(() => {
    setUpdateCartItems(cartItems)
}, [cartItems])

console.log(updateCartItems)

return (
   {cartItems?.map((item, index) => {
        const [itemQty, setItemQty] = useState(item.quantity)
        console.log(itemQty)

        const totalPrice = item.price * itemQty
        console.log(totalPrice)

        const handleIncrease = () => {
            if(itemQty < 10){
               setItemQty(itemQty + 1)
            } 
            setUpdateCartItems({...item, quantity: itemQty})
        }
                                        // console.log(updateCartItems)
        const handleDecrease = () => {
            if(itemQty > 1){
               setItemQty(itemQty - 1)
            }
        } 

     <div className="cart-plus-minus">
         <div className="dec qtybutton" onClick={handleDecrease}>
            - 
         </div>
         <input type="text" className="cart-plus-minus-box" name='qtybutton' value={itemQty} onChange={(e) => setItemQty(parseInt(e.target.value))}/>
         <div className="inc qtybutton" onClick={handleIncrease}>
             + 
          </div>
     </div> 
)
```

In this React project, I am using redux state management to maintain the state of `cartItems`. However, when I trying to update the cart item quantity by clicking the buttons. The `itemQty` can be updated but the `updateCartItems` of the corresponding item quantity is still remain unchanged. Any solutions that can have the `updateCartItems` update with the quantity changed? Also are there any methods can have the `cartItems` of the corresponding item quantity updated rather than extending the original array?

Comment: Your code is so... unhinged that i don't even know where to start. **_Always_** use hooks on top level, not like what you did; `setState` is asynchronous, please make sure to read the latest value of the state for the `setUpdateCartItems()`, or manually update the value for it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to maintain as your source of truth? You've quantity in local state and are incorrectly using the `useState` hook in a nested function, and the cart data is in your Redux store. The UI should be dispatching actions to the store to update item quantities in the store. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: If it helps, I answered a *very similar* and better formulated post earlier today regarding updating item quantities in a cart: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841545/increment-decrement-button-react-js-redux This post is very likely a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to update state locally as well as by using redux. You want to make sure you are using redux for the right reason and update state accordingly. Remember you only want one source of truth so you dont have to manage state in two places. As you application get larger it can become problematic.

If you want to update state via redux you will need to dispatch the payload to an action creator.

```
const { cartItems, loading: cartLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleIncrease = (item) => {
    if (item.quantity < 10) {
        dispatch(updateCartItemQuantity(item.id, item.quantity + 1));
    }
};

const handleDecrease = (item) => {
    if (item.quantity > 1) {
        dispatch(updateCartItemQuantity(item.id, item.quantity - 1));
    }
};


return (
    {cartItems?.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="cart-plus-minus">
            <div className="dec qtybutton" onClick={() => handleDecrease(item)}>
                - 
            </div>
            <input type="text" className="cart-plus-minus-box" name='qtybutton' value={item.quantity} readOnly />
            <div className="inc qtybutton" onClick={() => handleIncrease(item)}>
                + 
            </div>
        </div>
    ))}
);
```

Comment: So for the reducer action payload in ```updateCartItemQuantity``` how should I write?